# Determining ActionScript version based on results of a flash decompiler

Tags: flash, actionscript, decompiling

I need to determine the ActionScript Version of a SWF file from within an application without using another SWF to get the information, and as I was doing research for this, I came across [this](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/) flash decompiler.

I used this tool to decompile several flash files that I already knew that ActionScript version of, and I noticed a difference between the ActionScript 2 files and ActionScript 3. In this screenshot:[(unfortunately I cannot post images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGqWS.png), you can see that the the bottom SWF called `Cardio Sequence.swf`, which is an ActionScript 3 file,  has a file in the `scripts` folder called `MainTimeline`.

In all the files that I tested, the ActionScript 3 files had this `MainTimeline` file, whereas the ActionScript 2 ones did not. Is there any way that I can get this information to be readable as a string inside of another application (i. e. `if (scripttext.MainTimeline != null) {doSomething}`)? Or is this even a feasible way of determining the ActionScript version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileAttributes tag in the SWF file contains a flag that indicates whether the SWF uses AVM1 (ActionScript 1.0/2.0) or AVM2 (ActionScript 3.0). If this tag is omitted, the SWF is for Flash Player 7 or earlier and can only be AVM1. More info is in the [SWF specs](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf).

You can use any SWF parsing library or decompiler of your choice to look for this tag. The particular JPEXS decompiler supports [command line options](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/features/commandline/) to output a list of SWF tags, AS2, and/or AS3 scripts to a file. This includes the `-dumpSWF`, `-dumpAS2`, and `-dumpAS3` command line arguments. For example:

`ffdec.bat -dumpSWF myfile.swf`

Comment: That just so happens to be the decompiler I was using! Thanks a ton for the info!

Comment: This is the text that I got from using the -dumpSWF on a swf that is known to be AS2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/smrcuw98jh7essm/NewSwfDump.txt?dl=0   Now how do I go about interpreting this file so I know how to read it for ActionScript versions that are unknown?

Comment: The 4th bit of the FileAttributes tag is what determines the ActionScript version. See the [FileAttributes section of the SWF specs](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf), page 57. In the example you posted, the 4th bit in the 1st byte of the FileAttributes tag is 0, so you know it's an ActionScript 2 file.

Comment: Simpler is to just check for the action tags themselves; ActionScript 2 files will contain DoAction tags. ActionScript 3 files will contain DoABC tags. They can't be mixed.

If a file has no ActionScript, you have to check the FileAttributes tag to determine the AS version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a major problem. FFDEC is not an option for me to use because it requires java. Are there any other decompilers that you know of with similar features?

Comment: The reason being that java is too intensive for the process to run on my lower-end machines when combined with the application that is going to call the batch file to run the command.